# The method builder() is undefined for the type BuilderExample

Tags: java, eclipse, lombok

```
package ee;
import lombok.Builder;
@Builder
public class BuilderExample {
        public String foo;
        public String ha;
}

package ee;
import ee.BuilderExample ;
public class Main{
public static void main(String a[]){
BuilderExample b=BuilderExample.builder().foo("hi").ha("anything").build();
}}
```

In this code it shows an error The method builder() is undefined for the type BuilderExample
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method builder() is undefined for the type BuilderExample
showing an error like this why?

Comment: Lombok is not working. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Builder added in BuilderExample

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909672/how-to-use-lombok-builder-annotation-on-methods

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Answer (score 11):

Follow the below steps for eclipse/STS

1. Close your IDE
2. Download the Lombok jar from the https://projectlombok.org/download
3. Double click the jar
4. Follow the steps mentioned in the https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse
5. Open your IDE

If it is still not resolved then close your project and open again.

Hope it works.

Comment: It works for me, just added STS path to Lombok jar, thank you

Answer (score 8):

I faced the issue in both Intellij and eclipse
Just by installing the lombok, we can simply erradicate the issue

Infact I have followed the answers in this question to solve the issue, but making it even more clear and understandable for layman also

**Step 1:**

Close your IDE.

**Step 2:**

Download lombox jar => https://projectlombok.org/download

**Step 3:**

Run the jar. To run the jar, Open command prompt in the jar location and enter below command

```
java -jar lombok.jar
```

After giving this command It will prompt you something like this

[image]

**If your IDE is not there is in default locations, you will encounter such issues
Click OK and specify the path of your IDE ex: Eclipse**

[image]

**After Specifying the path, the plugin will the installed**

[image: enter code here]

**Step 4 :**

Open your IDE and ReBuild your project

Now you won't face any issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse, make sure lombok is installed correctly. You can verify that in the Eclipse About dialog, as described at [the lombok website](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

Install lombok in your eclipse.
Do the following steps

1. Help->install new software
2. Type https://projectlombok.org/p2
3. Add and finish.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio Code users, the solution is add the following dependency to `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

Sources:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GabrielBB.vscode-lombok
- https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven
- https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Answer (score 0):

Error: The method builder() is undefined for the type BuilderExample in vs code.

My Soln: For VS Code and press Ctrl + Shift + X to open extension manager. Type lombok and click install. Reload VS Code when asked.

Then add the following dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Sources:**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GabrielBB.vscode-lombok

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot starters, using VS Code, just install Lombok extension. The dependencies are already added in pom.xml file [Thanks Siddharth.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69870367/18301333).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to import all of lombok.

```
import lombok.*;
```